# Pull value from array to SQL based on name in array

Tags: sql, json, automation

so I'm trying to pass a JSON payload to SQL and import a specific column

the JSON side has a segment that looks like this

```
"Custom":[
  {"id":100,
   "value" 8
  },
  {"id":200,
   "value" 25
  }
```

So ideally I would like to only insert into SQL the value in the array for when id = 200

I know that something along the lines of this on the SQL side works

```
custom_entry int '$.custom[2].value'
```

While that would likely do the trick, its also likely and possible that more items will be added and the order of the IDs in the array will get switched around and end up maybe pulling in the incorrect values before we can notice. Is there any way anyone knows of to specify the value when ID = 200?

Answer (score 0):

Here we can use a method described in this article :
https://www.pauric.blog/How-To-Import-JSON-To-SQL-Server/

Just tried out the same from article (copied same code)
JSON file :

```
    {
  "Custom":[
  {"id":100,
   "value":8
   },
  {"id":200,
  "value":25
  },
  {"id":100,
  "value":55
  }
  ]
}
```

SQL code to get only 200 value:

```
DECLARE @JSON VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @JSON = BulkColumn
FROM OPENROWSET 
(BULK 'C:\Users\KV_Prashant\Desktop\sample.json', SINGLE_CLOB) 
AS j

SELECT id,value
FROM OPENJSON (@JSON, '$.Custom')
  WITH (id int,
        value INT, 
        [data] NVARCHAR(MAX) AS JSON)
where id = 200
```

Output:

```
id  value
200  25
```

now you can see all the values for id 200 and do any operation over it.
inside with we need to specify exact name of JSON fields.